# How to output resultant documents from Weka text-classification

Tags: machine-learning, weka, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

So we are running a multinomial naive bayes classification algorithm on a set of 15k tweets. We first break up each tweet into a vector of word features based on Weka's StringToWordVector function. We then save the results to a new arff file to user as our training set. We repeat this process with another set of 5k tweets and re-evaluate the test set using the same model derived from our training set.

What we would like to do is to output each sentence that weka classified in the test set along with its classification... We can see the general information (Precision, recall, f-score) of the performance and accuracy of the algorithm but we cannot see the individual sentences that were classified by weka, based on our classifier... Is there anyway to do this?

Another problem is that ultimately our professor will give us 20k more tweets and expect us to classify this new document. We are not sure how to do this however as:

```
All of the data we have been working with has been classified manually, both the training and test sets...
however the data we will be getting from the professor will be UNclassified... How can we 
reevaluate our model on the unclassified data if Weka requires that the attribute information must
be the same as the set used to form the model and the test set we are evaluating against?
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to acomplish these tasks is using a `FilteredClassifier`. This kind of classifier integrates a `Filter` and a `Classifier`, so you can connect a `StringToWordVector` filter with the classifier you prefer (`J48`, `NaiveBayes`, whatever), and you will be always keeping the original training set (unprocessed text), and applying the classifier to new tweets (unprocessed) by using the vocabular derived by the `StringToWordVector` filter.

You can see how to do this in the command line in "[Command Line Functions for Text Mining in WEKA](http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.com.es/2013/04/command-line-functions-for-text-mining.html)" and via a program in "[A Simple Text Classifier in Java with WEKA](http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.com.es/2013/04/a-simple-text-classifier-in-java-with.html)".